# Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar theme affects rendering elements in constraint layout

Tags: android, themes, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack, material-components

I used ***Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar*** theme and it seems to be affecting constrained layout which is some of elements(such as buttons) can not see in the "Design and Blueprint". But they are appearing properly when the app is running.

I tried the following steps but no use.

1) Try to clean the project

2) Try to invalidate and restart Android Studio

3) Try Rebuilding the project

I tried adding Base key word but it seems to be wrong.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

I'm currently using the latest dependency which is 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'

It seems to be ok with early dependency such as    'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' but I'm wondering why it is not working with the latest releases.

I could use different theme which do not have material components and overcome this problem as well, but it is not what I'm expecting.

Your answers and comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using? You might try using a newer version to see if it has been fixed.

Comment: @CameronKetcham I'm using the latest version. Now I'm using 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0' and It works fine. Is it a bug or something with 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07' ?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Created https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134566530

Comment: @CameronKetcham Thanks...

Comment: First Try Latest Version of Android Studio, then might be your layout file code is not accurate post your code file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is directly related to the version of material design.  I used the latest version of android studio with latest version material design in the constraint layout. The same issue happened when I dropped  a button from the palette to layout, it made the layout vanish and I changed the theme to the default, it also worked fine. But as u said, I should use material design. When I used latest material design version( com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0), it didn't work but when I used **com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0**, it worked fine. That's why u can change the version to find the one which is compatible and not buggy.